# Use Dapper to convert a collection of objects to a TableValuedParameter

Tags: dapper, table-valued-parameters

I'm trying to use TVP in dapper to insert several rows at once like this:

```
                con.Execute(@"
INSERT INTO Author (
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ParentAuthor
)
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ParentAuthor
FROM @TVP
"
                    , new[]
                    {
                        new Author { FirstName = "Roger", LastName = "Smith", ParentAuthor = 1},
                        new Author { FirstName = "Stan", LastName = "Smith"},
                        new Author { FirstName = "Haley", LastName = "Smith"},
                        new Author { FirstName = "Francine", LastName = "Ling"}
                    } // .AsTableValuedParameter() => not working
                );
```

But is there a convenient way to convert a collection of object into a TableValuedParameter?

Answer (score 0):

I found out about [fast-member](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) and it then simply can be done like this:

```
                var items = new[]
                {
                    new Author {FirstName = "Roger", LastName = "Smith", ParentAuthor = 1},
                    new Author {FirstName = "Stan", LastName = "Smith"},
                    new Author {FirstName = "Haley", LastName = "Smith"},
                    new Author {FirstName = "Francine", LastName = "Ling"}
                };

                var table = new DataTable();
                using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(
                    items,
                    nameof(Author.FirstName),
                    nameof(Author.LastName),
                    nameof(Author.ParentAuthor)
                ))
                {
                    table.Load(reader);
                }

                con.Execute(@"
INSERT INTO Author (
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ParentAuthor
)
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ParentAuthor
FROM @TVP
"
                    , new { TVP = table.AsTableValuedParameter("TVP_Author") }
                );
```

If there is a similar functionnality built-in dapper, I'd still like to know.